# Converting vector types in a tibble

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a two tibbles for example:

```
>a.tibble

names value1 value2
<chr> <chr>  <chr>
  a    3.14   2.18
  b    2.5    6.28

>b.tibble

names value1 value2
<chr> <chr>  <chr>
  a    1       0
  b    0       0
```

The first column in each of these tibbles needs to be a character type. In `a.tibble`, values need to be doubles not characters. In `b.tibble` the values need to be factors not characters. How do I change the types of the values in both of these tibbles? Is the only way to change the types to convert the tibble to a dataframe, then change the types, then convert back to a tibble?

Comment: How did these get to be character vectors in the first place?  Check out `type_convert` from package readr as one option.

Comment: Types were correct when first read from the file, after transposing the tibble all of the vectors became characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use class to assign the class of a column of an existing tibble. Run this  example:

```
a.tibble <- tibble::data_frame(name = c("a","b"),value1=c(3.14,2.5),value2=c(2.18,6.28))
class(a.tibble[[2]])<-"character"
a.tibble # second column will be character
class(a.tibble[[2]])<-"numeric"
a.tibble # second column is numeric again
```

Wondering as aosmith in the comment below question, how you got there in the first place? Transpose on a tibble returns a matrix, not a tibble.